# Spring framework - в каком слое хранить бизнес-логику

Tags: spring, архитектура, service, model, dao

Есть шаблон MVC. Контроллер принимает запрос и просто дергает методы из модели. В моделях хранится вся бизнес-логика. 
Модели завязаны друг на друга, т.е. модели Student и Courses могут знать друг о друге, полной изоляции не бывает. И обращение к БД идет из самой же модели, т.е. модель сама знает как ей обращаться в базу чтобы получить всех студентов с GPA>=3.5. Для этого в модели создается метод `findByGpa(Double gpa){}`.
В модели мы описываем все, что умеет делать наша сущность. Например, updateStatus(), getCourse(), retakeExam() и т.д. И эти методы потом могут многократно использоваться из контроллера, друг из друга, или из других моделей.

В Spring столкнулся с другим подходом, который еще не совсем понятен.

- Есть StudentDto, в нем только поля, никаких методов.
- Есть StudentDao, в нем только обращения в БД в таблицу studens, и ни
  в какую больше. Поэтому в этом классе только crud-методы.
- Есть StudentRepository, в нем то же что и в dao, но можно обращаться
  в разные таблицы. Но это не точно.
- Есть StudentService - здесь логика по Student.
- Есть StudentController - он только дергает методы из Service.
- Есть view - получает данные от controller и рендерит вью.

Первый вопрос - какие различия между dao и repository.
Второй вопрос более объемный.
Если у приложения появляется новое требование, то в старом подходе я бы из контроллера последовательно вызвал методы модели, если их недостаточно - добавил бы модели новое "умение", но в основном я бы переиспользовал уже реализованные его методы. И получил бы результат.

В spring framework если я буду в Service-слое создавать новый метод для каждой новой задачи, где строчка за строчкой буду реализовывать каждый шаг нового требования, то ни о каком переиспользовании методов речи не идет. И мой Service - это просто свалка кода, которая разрастается при малейшем расширении.

Как нужно организовать код, чтобы применить все преимущества ООП и легко масштабировать, управлять кодом?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, Вы должны честно ответить себе на вопрос: а нужны Вам сейчас все эти заморочки с чистотой кода, слоями и прочими академическими штуками? Если Вы в начале пути освоения ремесла построения ПО, то просто учитесь писать код, чтоб он работал. Изучайте инфраструктуру. Пробуйте на практике все, что узнали в книгах.

По поводу, что, где, и как располагать:
Всё очень относительно в этом вопросе. Как правило, логику надо делить по классам, соблюдая (желательно) принцип единой ответственности. Бизнес-логику реализовывать через сервисы, но опять же не забывая про тот самый принцип. Лично у меня выработался такой подход (не претендующий на правильность):

- Контроллер обслуживает одну вьюху
- Контроллер только передает запросы фронта в слой с бизнес-логикой
- Если одного сервиса достаточно для обслуживания контроллера, то оставляем его, ежели сервисов много, объединяем их в фасад

Про DAO и Repository не могу ничего умного Вам рассказать, у меня на проекте ActiveRecord паттерн используется, иногда рождаются DAO, используются они, чтоб получить объекты из БД, перегнать их в DTO и отдать вопрошающему сервису.

> Как нужно организовать код, чтобы применить все преимущества ООП и легко масштабировать, управлять кодом?

Про это неплохо рассказывает дядя Боб (Роберт Мартин) в свой книге "Чистый код". Советую к прочтению, если Вас эта тема волнует.